# WCF 4.0 : WebMessageFormat.Json not working with WCF REST Template

Tags: wcf

Downloaded the WCF REST Template from [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd) location.

The default response format is XML, which works great. However, when I try to get a JSON response, I still get XML.

This is my modified code -

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public List<SampleItem> GetCollection()
    {
        // TODO: Replace the current implementation to return a collection of SampleItem instances
        return new List<SampleItem>() { new SampleItem() { Id = 1, StringValue = "Hello" } };
    }
```

Note the ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json. That is the only change I did to that template.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Figured out. `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled` property for standardendpoint should be set to `false` and defaultOutgoingReponseFormat should be set to `Json`.

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" 
    automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" 
    defaultOutgoingResponseFormat ="Json" />
```

Comment: +1 interesting that my silverlight app in IE would get json, while same app running in firefox 4 would get xml.  This fixed it though.

Comment: +1 Unbelievable how `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json` is silently ignored, and you have to figure this out!  WCF would be utterly unusable without Google

Comment: @Andomar It's not only WCF most of the MS products are like that

Comment: In .NET 4.0, I only needed to set automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false". The method was tagged with  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json and it worked. No need to set defaultOutgoingResponseFormat

Comment: Setting `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"` would be just enough to circumvent the bug. `defaultOutgoingResponseFormat` property comes into play when you haven't specified the `WebMessageFormat` explicitly.

Comment: I also have same issue, but these settings are also not working for me

Comment: @Andomar, friend can u help me in this issue?

Answer (score 6):

```
 <system.serviceModel>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
        <standardEndpoints>
            <webHttpEndpoint>
                <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
            </webHttpEndpoint>
        </standardEndpoints>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Changes to 2 attributes within the web.config will fix it:

- `automaticFormatSelectionEnabled=false`
- `defaultOutgoingResponseFormat=Json` (edited: from "true")

Answer (score 5):

For me, setting the response format to JSON in the WebGet attribute doesn't work.  Setting it in the body of the method does;

```
// This works
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Format = WebMessageFormat.Json;
return jsonData;


// This doesn't work
`[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/conditions?term={term}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]`
```

Answer (score 1):

Click -> [reference links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.webhttpendpoint.automaticformatselectionenabled.aspx)

"When automatic format selection is enabled, the infrastructure parses the Accept header of the request message and determines the most appropriate response format. If the Accept header does not specify a suitable response format, the infrastructure uses the Content-Type of the request message or the default response format of the operation."

**EDIT:** this link might get you moving ahead 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/01/wcf-webhttp-service-returns-http-415-unsupported-media-type.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting issues like this every time I tried to create a JSON web service.

Now, I just follow the steps shown here.

https://web.archive.org/web/20180331113359/http://mikesknowledgebase.com/pages/Services/WebServices-Page1.htm

It shows how to create a JSON web service, step-by-step, with screenshots and examples.

Hope this helps.