# Return JSON from WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, json, .net-3.5, basichttpbinding

my WCF service is in .net framework 3.5,this WCF service will be used by PHP, so i have used basicHttpBinding (please suggest if any other better one).

i am using below code/attribut on function to return JSON.

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

but its not returning JSON (its returning object).
Please help me.

NOTE: i found a solution but its for .NET Framework 4.0. but i need solution for 3.5.
[WCF 4.0 : WebMessageFormat.Json not working with WCF REST Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781512/wcf-4-0-webmessageformat-json-not-working-with-wcf-rest-template)
Thanks

Comment: Please dont suggest me to create JSON manually.. its my last option..

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the AspNetCompatability attribute to your service implementation class?

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class ServiceImpl{
}
```

Also, change you might need to change your binding to `webHttpBinding` as `basicHttpBinding` is for SOAP rather than Json

Comment: @Jaimal: yes, but no JSON result

Comment: You also need to add a <webHttp /> behaviour to your endpoint's behaviour

Comment: after adding <webHttp> i am getting this error: The endpoint at 'http://localhost:4569/Service1.svc' does not have a Binding with the None MessageVersion.  'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebHttpBehavior' is only intended for use with WebHttpBinding or similar bindings.

Comment: You need to change your binding to webHttpBinding

Comment: Yes it will be accessible using PHP.

Comment: @Jaimal: i am still not able to get JSON.. can you please provide me a sample or any link

Comment: What response are you getting?