# Does WebMessageFomat.Json will work only for WebHTTPBinding?

Tags: asp.net, json, web-services, wcf, rest

I am creating a WCF service and I am planning to set the message format as JSON. But when I use BasicHttpBinding, I get the response and request in XML format. I am not sure does that mean this WebMessageFormat.Json can be used only in WEBHttpBinding (REST)? I have an understanding that SOAP uses only XML but this MessageFormat attribute arise a question in me whether JSON format can be used across all binding.

[image: Contract]
[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: you would need to use webHttpBinding.  basicHttpBinding is only used with SOAP (xml response). Also check this [query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031364/return-json-from-wcf)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.