# How to Call WCF service from ajax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I have a WCF service as given below-

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Sync
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke]
    public string SyncDataNow(UserData obj)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MavenifyEntities db = new MavenifyEntities())
            {
                bool userExist = db.Users.Any(u => u.Id == obj.UserId);
                if (userExist)
                {
                    DataSync data = new DataSync();
                    data.UserId = obj.UserId;
                    data.TempId = obj.TempId;
                    data.Content = obj.Content;
                    data.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    db.DataSyncs.Add(data);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "0";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class UserData
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Content { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string TempId { get; set; }
}
```

When I am calling this service from POSTMAN, it receives null data, Please help me to find out what's wrong I am doing.

I am sending raw data in json format like-

> {"UserData":{"UserId":"1","TempId":"asdbsjiadf","Content":"Hello"}}.

my web.config entries are-

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="PhoneSync.SyncAspNetAjaxBehavior">
      <enableWebScript />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<services>
  <service name="PhoneSync.Sync">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="PhoneSync.SyncAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PhoneSync.Sync" /> 
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Make sure that request/response by default is json. I would specify that explicitly in [WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem by changing the name "UserData" to "obj" in my json i.e. changing

> {"UserData":{"UserId":"1","TempId":"asdbsjiadf","Content":"Hello"}}

to

> {"obj":{"UserId":"1","TempId":"asdbsjiadf","Content":"Hello"}}

now I am receiving the data in my services. But I am unable to get why it is happening. Please share the cause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Wcf Rest `WebHttpBinding` also You will face with `Cross Domain Messaging` issue. So You will disable cross messaging security or create own behavior for jsonp

also your message should be `{"UserId":"1","TempId":"asdbsjiadf","Content":"Hello"}` for your signature.
if you want to use `{"UserData":{"UserId":"1","TempId":"asdbsjiadf","Content":"Hello"}}` you should wrap it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that request/response by default is **Json**. I would specify that explicitly in **[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]**

And maybe make sense do configure some options [like suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781512/wcf-4-0-webmessageformat-json-not-working-with-wcf-rest-template)